# how can i contact the inventor and owner of this patent to be able to buy the rights to this patent?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, design-patent, vibrating, mattress

In reference to the patent: [US20020111572](https://www.google.com/patents/US20020111572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a patent application, not a patent. It was abandoned in 2003 so at this point it seems unlikely it will ever be a patent. You can determine this for yourself at the US Public Pair site.